Error in making matplotlib figure interactive when using in panel dashboard
Hello Stackoverflow community,
I am new to panel dashboard and understand basic python. I am currently working on a side project and using panel for creating dashboard. I am using python 3.11.5, matplotlib 3.9.2 and panel 1.4.4.
The matplotlib figures are generated from other module and I am using this generated figures in dashboard.
The dashboard works fine when the modal_plot_pane = pn.pane.Matplotlib(tight=True, interactive = False), but gives error when interactive = True
Following is the error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_dpi'.
I tried by updating the matplotlib but it is not working. I do not want to use plotly, holoviews although this are better alternative for interactive figures.
I am looking for solution to resolve the above error.
Thank you for the suggestions.
